# Проверка, соответствует ли значение input заданному type

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, веб-программирование, frontend

Есть несколько полей ввода. Например,

```html
<input type="email" required>
<input type="number" required>
```

нужно при помощи jquery проверить, соответствуют ли введенные значения заданному типу, а именно действительно ли email прописан в поле с type="email".

Есть ли что-то стандартное или лучше писать свою функцию?

Answer (score 1):

Можете использовать input-атрибут pattern ([тут за атрибуты](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) и [в общем](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html5-form-validation-with-the-pattern-attribute--cms-25145)):

```html
<form>
  <input type="email" 
    pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" 
    required />
  <input type="number" required />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

[поддержка pattern браузерами](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern)

Можете писать валидаторы. Вот пример на jQuery:

```js
let $form = $('form#form-id'),
  pattern = new RegExp(/^[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i);
$form.on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let email = $(this).find('input#email');
  if (!pattern.test(email.val())) {
    email.css('border','1px solid red').focus();
    return false;
  }
  console.log('keep doing something');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form-id">
  <input id="email" type="text" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Можете использовать сторонние библиотеки. Например [validatejs](https://validatejs.org)